# Recommend regular expression plugin for gedit?

Tags: gedit

I would like to do some search and/or replace using regular expression in gedit. If I am correct, by default it is impossible to do this. So I was wondering if someone can recommend some nice plugin for this feature? How to install such plugin? Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See - https://wiki.gnome.org/GeditPlugins. The regular expression plugin is linked there as well as even more plugins and instructions on installation - (at the bottom of the page).

Comment: Thanks! I installed gedit-plugins. Now under Edit->Preference->Plugins, which one can provide the regular expression feature? At the page you linked, I didn't find related plugins. Maybe I miss something?

Comment: @Tim The plugins are rather far down the page (sorry I cannot provide a direct link without having you download files - they are called regular expression plugins - just hit ctrl+f in your browser to find them on that page.

Comment: Thanks! I see the plugin now. Is it already included in gedit-plugins, which is available in Synaptic package manager? Or I have to download it from the webpage you linked?

Comment: @Tim I thought it was, but after checking I think you have to download it :P

Answer (score 6):

The best regular expression plugin is [`advanced-find`](http://code.google.com/p/advanced-find/). Check it out and I am sure you'll be satisfied.